# Qunit asyncTest doesn't resolve

Tags: qunit

Hi I'm setting up some async tests - before hand to check things are working ok, I've copied the following from the jquery site.

```
asyncTest("a test", function() {

      setTimeout(function(){
        start();
        ok(true, "always fine");
      }, 13);
    });
```

The test just runs and runs.

The runner just shows that the test is running;

```
Running Server Tests: a test 
Running: 
Server Tests: a test
```

Where could I be going wrong I wonder. I have require.js on the page but in this case surely that doesn't matter. Any advice/pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that has the problem.
this fixed it for me.

```
asyncTest("a test", 1, function() {

  setTimeout(function(){
    QUnit.start();
    ok(true, "always fine");
  }, 10);


});
```

In my case I had a function named start on the page - whoops!

Comment: I am facing the same problem..QUnit.start() doesn't help...any inputs?

Comment: Sorry for the above comment. I was using sinon js and qunit together and sinon sets faketimers to true. For anyone else who is facing this issue do the following:
      sinon.config.useFakeTimers = false

Comment: Well that's a very annoying default configuration.